# clear image in only one dropify

Tags: jquery, dropify

[Dropify from Github](http://jeremyfagis.github.io/dropify/)

Anybody can help me with this? I want to manually remove uploaded image inside this dropify. I have more than one dropify in a page. Whenever I try to remove, all of the images inside each dropify will be removed.

Can someone help me? Because I think this library is already inactive.

Whenever I use this code in one dropify, all other dropify images will also be removed.

```
$(".dropify-clear").click();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`".dropify-clear"` refers to all elements with the class name `dropify-clear`.

You should add an id to the specific element you want to remove and then refer to it in jQuery like this: `"#idName"`

Answer (score 6):

`$(".dropify-clear").trigger("click");` worked for me

Answer (score 3):

Get the parent wrapper of the element with the id, then trigger the click on the remove button.

for example

```
$('#image1').parent().find(".dropify-clear").trigger('click');
```

Answer (score 1):

Although its late to answer this question but I want to share my knowledge with others. You can face two situation when you will have to do this. I am sharing method for both situations.

1. When there is a single dropifyin your file
2. When there are multiple dropify in your file

Solution for 1 dropify:

```
    $(".dropify-clear").trigger("click");
```

Solution for multiple dropifies:

```
    $("#imageid").next(".dropify-clear").trigger("click");
```

Or if multiple dropifies in loop

```
    $(this).next(".dropify-clear").trigger("click");
```

Comment: Thank you ** $(".dropify-clear").trigger("click");  **worked for me